# How to include Python pip3 modules in OpenWRT image

Tags: openwrt

I'm going to include pip3 modules in OpenWRT image, so it won't require other dependencies after installed OpenWRT image.

For example, I'm going to include `argparse` module in OpenWRT image.
This module may be installed by the following command in initial OpenWRT image:

```
opkg install python3
pip3 install argparse
```

How can I include them in initial OpenWRT firmware?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, run `make menuconfig`, and then select `Languages -> Python`, and then select `python3,python3-pip`, then save and then exit.

Next, run `./scripts/env new py3-argparse` to create a build environment for your changes.

Finally, download the argparse library and place it in `files/lib/python3.6/site-packages`.

References:

[OpenWrt - Build Environments](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-developer/using-build-environments)

[Python3 - argparse (source)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/argparse.py)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: How would I do it if I want to include python 2.7 packages? Requests and schedule. I tried your commands but I'm getting back "mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/aaa/openwrt/scripts/env': File exists

Comment: Apparently, you are already using a build environment. To confirm this, run `./scripts/env list`. Additionally, packages for python 2.7 should go in `files/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, respectively.

Comment: @LucasRamage I'm trying to include these in the location that you mentioned above but after installing the update file on my board these packages are not installed. Can you help me? :)

Comment: Are you only having issues with the Python2.7 files, or with the Python3.6 files also?

Comment: @LucasRamage I tried only on 2.7 as my code is written for Python 2.7