# Is there a way to build OpenWrt firmware containing my custom python package and auto starting script?

Tags: python, embedded-linux, openwrt

I have a shell script that installs the software on the running device(Linkit Smart 7688 Duo with OpenWrt on board).
It contains my custom python package and a couple of different files.
I have managed to build OpenWrt for that board from source but I have no knowledge on how to build my custom script into the image. 
For example, I want my installation script to run at first bootup of the board. 
In my script I define a new /etc/init.d/ Service that runs at startup.

Can someone help me / provide with a tutorial on how to achieve what I wrote above? 
I looked for tutorials but none of them seem to cover my topic of interest.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a new 'package' with a Makefile that will use the OpenWRT build system to include it in the image. The documentation for this is fairly good and can be read here: https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-developer/packages

If you have any follow up questions in regards to building the image, or trouble compiling it all - do not be afraid to ask. It can be a tad bit difficult to understand at first.

Comment: hi! Thanks for your response! I have this bit:                                            PKG_NAME:=idna
PKG_VERSION:=2.6
PKG_RELEASE:=1
PKG_SOURCE:=idna-2.6.tar.gz
PKG_SOURCE_URL:=https://pypi.python.org/packages/f4/bd/0467d62790828c23c47fc1dfa1b1f052b24efdf5290f071c7a91d0d82fd3/
PKG_BUILD_DIR:=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_NAME)-$(PKG_VERSION)/ Is there a way to provide my package as a local tar.gz file instead of providing a pkg source url?

Comment: Yes, though there's little reason to do that, because you will have to manually install the files you will use. Note the `define Package/$(PKG_NAME)/install` part in the link I provided.

Comment: if I managed to run /compile and /install commands without errors. Where should I find my package in make menuconfig? Also define command wont work for me: "command define not found"

Comment: Sorry, I know now what was meant by 'define' statement. But the question about modules remains. Still can't install them

Comment: I managed to install my custom library and a couple of others. But I have a few problems with the requirements. How do I force the requirements to be installed? I didn't have a problem with requests, schedule, paho-mqtt but for example, requests need urllib3 which I tried to install. It throws this on compilation: "error in urllib3 setup command: 'extras_require' must be a dict whose values are strings or lists of strings". I found that ``` pip install --upgrade setuptools``` would fix it but how to implement it in the build process?

Comment: (@pawisoon) I am fairly sure that this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50218544/how-to-include-python-pip3-modules-in-openwrt-image answers your question fully.

Comment: I tried that solution and it won't work at all for 2.7